# create frequency table for from pivot table in python

Tags: python

I have a dataframe created using pivot_table() in python.

```
ID  A  B  C
43  0  1  1
28  1  1  1
70  1  0  1
```

My requirement is to get the number of times a pair of columns in {A,B,C} both have value 1, as shown below.

```
ID1    ID2   Frequency
A       B       1
A       C       2
B       C       2
```

The process would be to create a frequency matrix and then get the upper / lower triangle. But I am not sure what functions in python I can use to achieve the desired result.

Appreciate your help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from itertools import combinations
cols=list("ABC")
arr=[]
for el in combinations(cols, 2):
    arr.append([*el, df[list(el)].all(axis=1).sum()])

res=pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=["ID1", "ID2", "Frequency"])
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> res

  ID1 ID2  Frequency
0   A   B          1
1   A   C          2
2   B   C          2
```